# Función doPost para guardar valores desde URL

Tags: google-apps-script, http-post, http-get

Necesito poder obtener un valor en una URL de una implementación de google app script y se guarde en un sheets. He utilizado la función doGet y doPost pero no consigo guardar dicho texto.

mi código es

```
function doGet(){
 
 var HTMLString = "<style> h1,p {font-family: 'Helvitica', 'Arial'}</style>" 
 + "<h1>Hello World!</h1>"
 + "<p>Welcome to the Web App";
 
doPost()

 HTMLOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(HTMLString);
 return HTMLOutput
}

function doPost(e){
  var o = e; // la segunda columna es el nombre de la persona

  var libro = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var hoja =libro.getSheetByName("Hoja 1");
 hoja.appendRow([ "Prueba 1 columna", o, "columna3" , "columna4" ]);

}
```

y  la url

`https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwUG76QtXcbUr568nl6QXYB96PekgQ169N8ByrwiKSJ6DvLdfRU_slWLDjtUB5aZvf78w/exec`

Lo que necesito es poder guardar los datos desde la url  por ejemplo utilizando

`?action=get&name=NOMBREPERSONA`

quedando así:

`https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwUG76QtXcbUr568nl6QXYB96PekgQ169N8ByrwiKSJ6DvLdfRU_slWLDjtUB5aZvf78w/exec?action=get&name=NOMBREPERSONA`

Answer (score 0):

En la función `doGet` te faltó incluir el parámetro para recibir el objeto evento. A continuación la versión modificada

```
function doGet(e){
 
 var HTMLString = "<style> h1,p {font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial'}</style>" 
 + "<h1>Hello World!</h1>"
 + "<p>Welcome to the Web App";
 
 doPost(e)

 HTMLOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(HTMLString);
 return HTMLOutput
}
```

En la función `doPost`, si bien esta incluye el parámetro para recibir el objeto evento, el Array que pasas a `appendRow` no debería tener el objeto evento ya que este sólo debería tener datos de tipo `number`, `string`, `boolean` y/o `Date`. Considerando esto podrías reemplazar

```
hoja.appendRow([ "Prueba 1 columna", o, "columna3" , "columna4" ]);
```

por

```
hoja.appendRow([ "Prueba 1 columna", JSON.stringify(o), "columna3" , "columna4" ]);
```

o bien, para pasar sólo el valor de `name`, por

```
hoja.appendRow([ "Prueba 1 columna", o.parameter.name, "columna3" , "columna4" ]);
```